# Calling on Microsoft Access module in Python. Combining multiple Access tables into 1 single table

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, automation

I was recently tasked with automating the update process of some of my company's production data. Effectively what I am trying to do is establish an automated process where every evening a script downloads all the updated .dbf files from a ftp server, calls on a module in my Microsoft Access database that imports all the .dbf file tables into Access, then, once these tables are loaded into Access, combines all the data from the separate tables into one big table.

So far, I have implemented a python script to fetch the files, and have an Access module to import the .dbf files once they're downloaded, but I am unaware as to whether or not there exists a way to have all of these .dbf files import into a single table. Right now they import into about 253 respective tables that share identical formats and have a column that contains unique integers for each row.

My main focus now is creating a script that will: 1) Truncate my complete_db table each time it runs
2) iterate through each dbf file and append all rows to the complete_db table. 3) delete each individual dbf table after appending the rows to complete_db to save space. Any tips with how to achieve this with python would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Attached is an image of the module i'm using to import the files as well as what my table view panel looks like after importing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/47TCA.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MS Access can directly query `.dbf` files, consider an append query to your master table. Query will take the form. Explicitly write out the columns to avoid indexes or autonumber fields:

**SQL** *(hard-coded query)*

```sql
INSERT INTO complete_db
SELECT * FROM [myFile.dbf] IN 'C:\Path\To\Folder'[dBASE IV;];

-- OR

INSERT INTO complete_db (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM [myFile.dbf] IN 'C:\Path\To\Folder'[dBASE IV;];
```

**VBA** *(dynamic query)*

```vb
...
sFolderPath = "C:\Path\To\Folder"

For Each oFile in oFolder.Files
    If Right(oFile.Name, 3) = "dbf" Then
        sql = "INSERT INTO complete_db SELECT * FROM [" & oFile.Name & "]" _
                & " IN '" & sFolderPath & "'[dBASE IV;]"

        CurrentDb.Execute sql
    End If
Next oFile
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it yielded a similar result as before, except now it creates multiple tables named complete_db# depending on which file it is iterating through

Comment: Oddly enough I seem to be getting an invalid path error, but I'm not sure why because whenever I run the module using my original without the vba code that loads all the files into seperate tables, I use the same file path to great effect. I have tried changing the folder name and creating a new folder entirely to no avail.

Comment: What is your exact error (verbatim from message)? Inside the `For` loop and `if` logic, add `Debug.Print oFile.Name`. This way when sub errs out, you can now find the file that is causing the issue in Immediate Window (CTRL + G).

Comment: The exact error is " 'Well data headers' is not a valid path. make sure path name is spelled correctly, and that you are connected to server on which the file resides." After adding the debug print statement, the immediate window prints the first filename in my folder, and the stops the operation. Quite odd as I would think that the fact it is picking up the first file name would indicate a valid path.

Comment: It prints the first then errs out. Please post the folder and file names to your `dbf` files. Are you using square brackets as indicated and shown? Also, let's delete our lengthy, past comments here.

Comment: Here is an image of the VBA code as it exists currently as well as my target directory: https://imgur.com/IEuQ7tH . The API files are all named API 001-500 with the only unique name being APIFED.

Comment: I was now able to reproduce your error. Turns out it was the `oFolder.Name` which returns only the folder name and not full path. Instead, use the `sFolderPath` in the query. Additionally, you do not need to strip the extension, `.dbf` if you wrap name in square brackets `[...]`. See update.